# Infinite boot after Kernel Update or with liveDVD

Tags: boot, dual-boot, kernel, crash

I just receive my new Tp01-2000nf
Intel® Core™ i5-11400
Realtek RTL8821CE-M Wi-Fi® 802.11a/b/g/n/ac (1x1) et Bluetooth® 4.2
Intel® UHD 730
I installed in dual boot with Ubuntu LTS 20.04.1 with kernel 5.4.0-42.

When on grub I choose kernel 5.4.0-42, everything remains fine.

I burned Ubuntu LTS 20.04.3 and 21.04 which take an infinite time to boot.
Any update drive to the same situation.

log available here :
https://pastebin.com/FFUF63hU

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129765/discussion-on-question-by-jord-maogan-kernel-bug-at-mm-slub-c305).